# Check if a drop down list already contains a dynamically added item

Tags: c#, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I'm adding existing COM ports that are available on the system to a drop down list. So far I've got this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach (string port in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem t = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        t.Text = port;
        t.Checked = port == notifier.COMPort;
        t.Click += t_Click;
        setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(t);
    }
}
```

This works when adding the ports initially, however I want to check again for COM ports that have been added or removed before the user clicks on my drop down box to display the ports.

I see I can use `setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDOwnItems.ContainsKey()` but I have no idea what keys it uses when I add them.

This does not work:

```
private void setPortToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    foreach (string s in ports)
    {
        if (!setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem t = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            t.Text = s;
            t.Checked = s == notifier.COMPort;
            t.Click += t_Click;
            setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I specify what key it uses when I add the item or is there another way of checking existing items?

Comment: Did you try just `Contains(s)`?

Comment: `Contains(s)` would compare a string to a `ToolStripMenuItem` would it not? Therefore it would fail every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Making ContainsKey work

Try setting the `Name`-property on `ToolStripMenuItem`:

```
ToolStripMenuItem t = new ToolStripMenuItem();

t.Name = port; // Set the name of the ToolStripMenuItem to the port.

t.Text = port;
t.Checked = port == notifier.COMPort;
t.Click += t_Click;
setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(t);
```

Then `ContainsKey(s)` will work:

```
foreach (string s in ports)
{
    if (!setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.ContainsKey(s))
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

### Doing it with Linq

You can also use Linq to get all ports that are not in the ToolStrip:

```
string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();

var existingPorts = setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
    .OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
    .Select(t => t.Text); // Or t.Name if you set that.

var portsToAdd = ports.Except(existingPorts);
```

Now, all the ports that is not in the dropdown, will be in `portsToAdd`, so then you can add them without having to check more.

Read more [about Linq Except here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can check like this -

```
bool alreadyExist = setPortToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
                     .OfType<ToolStripItem>()
                      .Any(item => item.Text.Equals(s));
```

Comment: You could change `.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Text.Equals(s)) != null;` to `.Any(item => item.Text.Equals(s));`.